# How CyanogenMod Theme engine works?

Tags: themes, cyanogenmod

Is there someone can give me some suggestions about how the CM theme engine works?

I searched google ,but I find nothing about how the CM theme engine works.

I want to see the CM theme engine code ,but I dont know which point I shoud start.

I hope someone can share me some article about how CM theme engine works.

thx...

Answer (score 0):

The Cyanogenmod theme engine is actually the T-Mobile one (to my understanding). I'm not familiar with how it all works, but a good starting point might be:

https://code.google.com/p/android-theme/wiki/TMobileThemeEngine

note: I haven't tried this so I can't confirm that it will work... hopefully it will get you pointed in the right direction though.

Comment: Thx u reply.I have saw this doc,It's about how do make a theme for t-mobile theme manager,not about how the theme manager works.I think the  theme manager is also use the android theme to change the ico.and I have saw the ChaOS theme engine ,in Launcher it has search the .ctz theme for the app ico.but I dont know how it change the ico in Settings or MMs... may be use theme android base theme engine. I cant understand the ChaOS code very well.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the CM theme engine is actually the theme engine from the "sense" based roms from T-Mobile. This code was taken in by the community and raised as their own. The way the theme engine works is by backing up the stock theme in the phones storage. It the uses different png, ico, and xml files to replace the stock theme files (stock png, ico and xml) in the root dir (various files such as the system framework).

For example, a theme that only changes the backdrop in the notification shade would replace a png file found in system framework, as well as modify an xml file for the alpha channel (for ics and later). I really don't do too much with theming, but check out the XDA-DEVELOPERS forums for more info. They have anything android related you would ever need.